# Astro.js with module federation

Tags: webpack, webpack-module-federation, astrojs

I am trying to use module federation and webpack to build a frame that can load other micro frontends or components from other React/vite/astro projects. I am building this frame using Astro.js.

In my company their was already a frame like this using React.js (but of course with only using react elements) which I took a lot of inspiration from for my code.

Right now I have a webpack.config.js looking like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');
const federationConfig = require('./federation.config.json');
const { dependencies } = require('./package.json');

const port = 3000;

module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: `http://localhost:${port}/`,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js', '.json'],
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    port,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { modules: true },
          },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      ...federationConfig,
      shared: {
        astro: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: dependencies['astro'],
        },
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: dependencies['@astrojs/react'],
        },
        'react-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: dependencies['@types/react-dom'],
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

The problem I have stumbled on is that Astro is SSR. React you could just (using the HtmlWebPackPlugin point to the public/index.html. In Astro this is not the case.

Could Anyone have advice how I would be able to run Astro using this way. The best I could manage was this:
[image: Failed attempt]

when it should be looking like this:
[image: how It should look]

I am starting the application with a script "webpack serve -c ./webpack.typeless.config.js --mode development"

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what your goal is conceptually - Astro islands is a micro-frontend implementation, and Webpack module federation is another one. If you built in Astro, the output is HTML (mostly), whereas Webpack's federation is federated JS. So to federate an Astro output is not what I understand Webpack is for - you are better off just loading the HTML output into your page?

Comment: What I want to create is somewhat of a core to load in different micro frontends. I thought module federation would be the solution for this. I want the core to be able to download the micro frontends on runtime and use a d.ts file to load those in. I have been able to do this with only react, but I want to do the same in Astro to be able to load in microfrontends from other frameworks. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Module federation is for micro-frontends (MFE) potentially with different frameworks (react/vue etc). Astro is also for the same purpose (either through SSR / SSG to give plain HTML of framework components, or through "islands" for interactive JS enabled components). They are two build systems to achieve the same MFE end goal in different ways. So Astro Islands should already be able to do what I think you want without involving Webpack: https://docs.astro.build/en/concepts/islands/

Comment: From what I understand, Astro uses Vite as a core dependency, which uses Rollup as the bundler and SWC as compiler. Rollup bundles components in a different way to Webpack - you can examine this in the bundle output, where webpack generates one big function to execute, and Rollup retains a lot of separate definitions. So I would imagine it makes most sense to choose either Astro/Rollup or Webpack/Next.js/some other SSG framework, but not both?